# Failed to Configure Connector for Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: axapta, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-ax-2012, connector

I am trying to Configure connector for microsoft dynamic. Everything went fine when i configure Micorosft Dynamics CRM 2011. However when i tried to configure Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 i found this error (Pict 2).

[image: first picture]

[image: second picture]

I used :

1. User adminstrator domain to configure
2. The administartor as user used above already in AX.
3. Connectror for Microsoft Dynamics Version : 3.3.514
4. AX 2012 R2
5. CRM 2013

Does Anyone know how to resolve this ?

Please Help.

Regards, Frank.